# Passing data to Word application Addin:- custom remoting vs requestcomaddinautomationservice

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, remoting

I have a scenario where a word has an Application Addin which loads when word starts.

I have a wpf application which has to pass some data to addin.

Suggested way and conventional way seems to be [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/08/11/why-your-comaddin-object-should-derive-from-standardolemarshalobject.aspx)

However ,this is behaving erratically and throwing a variety of errors such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521421/intermittent-error-system-typeinitializationexception-type-constructor-threw-a)

Is there a better way to do this? I am thinking of using .Net remoting. Why not host a remote server when addin loads and have my wpf application be remoting client which can pass data to my addin?

Will there be any problem doing so?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass data from your application to your addin, you could use the file system for instance, using a temporary XML file.

AddIn automation is only necessary if you want to control the execution of the addin.

The solution depends on what exactly you want to do. Use a XML file (or whatever you want) if you just want to pass data, and load it when your addin starts. Override the RequestComAddInAutomationService() method in your addin if you want to control the addin from your WPF application.

However that may be, I've never encountered any error using addin automation.

Comment: thanks for the reply. My addin starts when the word opens , however there are couple of custom task panes which have some wpf controls which need to be loaded and some events wired when I call my remote method. When the document is closed all my controls are unloaded and will  be reloaded in same word window when my client app calls the method.

Comment: in short I need to control the addin.  I get exceptions like System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040637): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040637
   at Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIn.set_Connect(Boolean RetValue)